# Need Help Finding the Diagonal Matrix for a Given Eigenpair

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, diagonalization

I'm having trouble with a linear algebra question and I was hoping someone could help me out. The question asks:

"Using the candidate for $P$ given above (and NOT your answer to (c) if it was different), give the diagonal matrix $D$ such that $P^{-1} A P=D$."

From the question, I know that the following are eigenpairs of $A$:

$\left(1,\left[\begin{array}{c}-1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{array}\right]\right),\left(-3,\left[\begin{array}{c}-3 \\ 2 \\ 4\end{array}\right]\right)$, and $\left(-4,\left[\begin{array}{c}-2 \\ 1 \\ 3\end{array}\right]\right)$

The candidate for P is as follows:

$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -3 & -2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$

I've tried finding the inverse of $P$ and multiplying $P^{-1}AP$, but I'm not sure what to do next to get the diagonal matrix $D$.

Edit: I have the inverse of P, and I have A. A is a matrix which I have. I have the inverse of P. Do I multiple A by P by inverse of P?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a diagonal matrix, the eigenvalues are the diagonal entries.  You should edit the matrices $A$ and $P$ into your question

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I have the inverse of P, and I have A. A is a matrix which I have. I have the inverse of P. Do I multiple A by P by inverse of P?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Like that?

Comment: I see $P$ in the question but not $A$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner Sorry all I have for A is from this: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/488104216678760469/1087180797091512360/image.png

Comment: If you don't have $A$, it's difficult to multiply $A$ by $P$.  But per my initial comment I think $D=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&-3&0\\0&0&-4}$